# How much disk space does a test failover VM from a HyperV replica use?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v, replication, failover

We have a replica of our Exchange server running on Hyper-V. This replica creates a checkpoint every hour and keeps these checkpoints for 24 hours.

We would like to use the "test failover" option to test one of our checkpoints.

From what I understand, a new VM is created the moment you start a test failover and you use this VM to run your tests. Once testing is complete, you turn Test Failover off and the VM gets destroyed.

My question is: How much disk space does this test VM take up? Does it create a full copy of the replica?

Our Exchange server is about 700 GB, if the test failover VM is the same in size, our HDD will have no space left.

Clarification would be very much appreciated since I can't find a proper answer to this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does create a new VM, but it does not make a copy of the virtual disk files; it uses the existing ones from replication since they are already on the replica server as VHDX format. You might get a small amount of additional disk space utilization from the additional writes to disk from the test VM, but that would likely be minimal.